# How do I paint Pictureboxes to Panel?

Tags: c#

I have 2 pictureboxes on a panel at two separate locations which will become Hidden after a certain time. I would like to paint the pictureboxes background image to the panel at the exact points in which the picturebox controls lay. I have looked at the MSDN library but I cannot seem to find out how to do this.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "paint the pictureboxes background image to the panel"? Please explain better.

Comment: I think what you want to do is create a bitmap the size of the panel, paint the two images to the bitmap at the position of the pictures inside the panel and then assign the bitmap to the panel background.

Comment: I meant use the panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) event. I am trying to paint/draw the background image of a picturebox to the panel at the exact location of the picturebox control, and the painted image's size will be the same size of the picturebox. This image will be painted to panel1. Hope I explained it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(panel1.Size.Width, panel1.Size.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    g.DrawImage(pictureBox1.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(pictureBox1.Location, pictureBox1.Size));
    g.DrawImage(pictureBox2.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(pictureBox2.Location, pictureBox2.Size));
    g.Flush();
}

pictureBox1.Visible = false;
pictureBox2.Visible = false;
panel1.BackgroundImage = bitmap;
```

Or you can try using this:

```
public class PanelEx : Panel
{
    public PictureBox PictureBox1 { get; set; }
    public PictureBox PictureBox2 { get; set; }
    public bool IsBackgroundDrawn { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsBackgroundDrawn)
        {
            IsBackgroundDrawn = true;
            base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        if (PictureBox1 != null && PictureBox2 != null && !IsBackgroundDrawn)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(PictureBox1.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(PictureBox1.Location, PictureBox1.Size));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(PictureBox2.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(PictureBox2.Location, PictureBox2.Size));
            e.Graphics.Flush();

            PictureBox1.Visible = false;
            PictureBox2.Visible = false;
            this.BackgroundImage = bitmap;
            IsBackgroundDrawn = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks as though it'll do the trick. I'm gunna give it a try, thanks

Comment: this seems to make the panel flicker for some reason. I am looking for a way to draw these picturebox background images to the panel without any flicker.

Comment: Are you doing this on the panel_Paint(..)?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use the Paint event?

Comment: Yes, because I believe it'll be more useful for my application. I'm going to try one then the other to see which type I believe will be better for it, but I do think that the Paint event will in the end be the better choice. Alex do you have any ideas as to how to paint/draw the backgroundimages to the panel?

Comment: See my code changes. I added a custom Panel which would do what you need. This would require you to paint any control other that reside inside the panel besides the backgroundimages from the pictureboxes as I have removed the base.OnPaint(...) to remove the flickering.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Is there a way to do this without using a custom panel? I feel as tho there must be but I could be wrong. Edit: yes I believe you can, I used your above code but removed the "this.BackgroundImage = bitmap;" which gets the job done without using the custom panel. Usually that line of code is not for paint events, right alex?

Comment: Right, it is not for a paint event as the paint event is constantly painting.

Comment: Thanks for the help Alex, you were a great help. I marked your response as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by creating another 2 pictureboxes in the same location as the originals but without any picture in them. That way they will always be in the same spot as the originals. You leave the dupes empty so they show the background.

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear with my question IvoTops. I wanted to use the panel's paint event to paint the pictureboxes image to the panel.